# Adding images in webpage with bootstrap column

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm new in web developing. When i try to add an image on my new web page, i am facing some problems. i want to fix an image on top of the page and i used a 12 unit column. But when i run the web page there is some vacant space occurring after the image. help me to fix it. i want the width of the image is change when re-sizing the window and the height remain unchanged. here is my code

```
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>MyHealth template</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="bootstrap-3.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"     media="screen">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="row" id="header">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <img src="images/header.png">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: which side you getting space

Comment: I have set it on http://jsfiddle.net/wazan/22zg4cqv/ , pls tell what should come on it

Comment: on the right side. and a horizontal scrollbar also appeared

Comment: Check the url http://jsfiddle.net/wazan/22zg4cqv/4/ , it is working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my code

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>MyHealth template</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="bootstrap-3.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"     media="screen">
        <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--header-->
        <div class="row" id="header">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <img src="images/header.png" class="img-responsive header-img">
                <h1 class="header-head">My Health</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and the css file contain

```
    .header-img
    {
        z-index:9;
        width:100%;
        height:70px;
        position:absolute;
     }
     .header-head
     {
        color:#fff;
        font-family:harabara;
        margin-left:30px;
        z-index:10;
        position:absolute;
     }
```

this is working fine. But the image width is greater than width of browser window, how to set width to browser window width?

Answer (score 0):

Use the appropriate size of image and use `class="img-responsive"`

```
        <div class="row" id="header">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="images/header.png" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Check the Link](http://jsfiddle.net/wazan/22zg4cqv/4/) on jsfiddle

```
<div class="row" id="header">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://supportlanka.org/upload/75d21c49a621c4d63b65992fb1ac644c.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

It is working Fine

Comment: Thanks, but there is still a vacant space on the right side of the browser window